# Qual a diferença entre a arquitetura MVC e a MTV do Django?

Tags: python, aplicação-web, mvc, django

Gostaria de saber se há alguma diferença na prática entre essas duas arquiteturas.

Comment: Isso explica o porque do nome MTV: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.11/faq/general/, se ninguém formular uma resposta, talvez mais tarde eu arrisque algo.

Comment: Ninguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente 'e questao de nomenclatura, a view do django 'e exatamente o equivalente ao controler no MVC. Ja o template (M**T**V) e o arquivo html renderizado pela view (controller) que seria o equivalente a view no MVC

Model ( models.py)
Template ( arquivo HTML renderizado )
View ( views.py equivalente ao controller no MVC )

Comment: A "view" do Django não é exatamente o "controller" do MVC: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.0/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

Answer (score 2):

Esta é apenas uma questão mais conceitual. Os desenvolvedores do Django entendem que o controller é o próprio framework em si. Se pararmos para pensar isto faz sentido, já que quando você acessa alguma url da sua aplicação, a própria engine do Django faz o redirecionamento para a view correta, conforme você definiu nas configurações de url, ou seja, entende-se aqui que o papel do controller já está sendo realizado automaticamente. Logo, o método ou classe que vai fazer o processamento do que vai acontecer quando esta página específica for acessada foi denominado view. Finalmente, a forma como a sua página será apresentada (utilizando o dicionário de variáveis da view) consiste em um template.

Espero realmente ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

O MVC possui bem definidos os métodos de regras de negócio organizados pelo Controller. A View faz o papel de servir ao visual (front) as informações organizadas do Model, passando pelas regras de negócio do Controller.

O MTV já pressupõe uma série de organizações que são padrões já estabelecidos pela maneira do framework trabalhar. Ele facilita a parte do controller, não vendo a necessidade de escreve-lo como uma camada específica separada.

Se você souber obedecer os padrões do Django, muita coisa que seria controller já está resolvida. Se configurar corretamente as classes genéricas numa view, não precisará de controller nenhum na maioria das telas.

Seguindo esses padrões, o máximo que precisará de regra de negócios, numa situação bem específica personalizável, seria acrescentar algo no método save da model, para modificar algo nos dados.

As pessoas fazem confusão, pq muitas vezes o Django é utilizado por quem não conhece o MVT e escreve controllers como se ele fosse MVC. Mas a idéia do Django é não precisar escrever Controller e se você compreender a profundidade disso, escreverá menos.